# Error in program when parsing negative integers into an array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I am having a strange issue with one of my assignments. I am attempting to take integers from user input and store them in an array. After that, four recursive methods will be run on them to find different characteristics of those numbers. However, whenever I attempt to run the program with a negative integer in any of the indexes the program stops responding.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Assignment9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int index = 0;
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[100];
    InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inRead);
    String line = buffRead.readLine();

    try {
        while (!line.equals("0") && index < 100) {
            numbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(line);
            index++;
            line = buffRead.readLine();

        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Array index out of bound");
    }
`       int min = findMin(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
        int sumAtEven = computeSumAtEvenIndexes(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
        int divByThree = countDivisibleBy3(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
        System.out.println("The minimum number is " + min);
        System.out.println("The sum of numbers at even indexes is " + sumAtEven);
        System.out.println("The count of numbers that are divisible by 3 is " + divByThree);
        System.out.println("The maximum number among numbers that are less than the first number is " + maxLessThanFirst);


    }

    public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {
            return numbers[startIndex];
        } else if (findMin(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) < numbers[endIndex]) {
            return findMin(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
        } else {
            return numbers[endIndex];
        }

    }

    public static int computeSumAtEvenIndexes(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {
            if (startIndex % 2 == 0) {
                return numbers[startIndex];
            } else return 0;
        } else {
            if (endIndex % 2 == 0) {
                return computeSumAtEvenIndexes(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) + numbers[endIndex];
            } else {
                return computeSumAtEvenIndexes(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int countDivisibleBy3(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {
            if (numbers[startIndex] % 3 == 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (numbers[endIndex] == 0) {
                return countDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
            }
            if (numbers[endIndex] % 3 == 0) {
                return countDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) + 1;
            } else {
                return countDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the only relevant section of code that is necessary to understand the problem, I believe. If additional code is needed just ask. Thank you!

Comment: Overkill on input from user. Why not use a Scanner? Also, can you use an ArrayList? Lastly, You need to post the full working code or at least enough code that duplicates your problem.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I agree. Requirement of the assignment for some reason.

Comment: I just ran the code you posted and there is no problem.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I added the all the code. Really? Mine still is not working. If I enter any negative number once a zero is entered the program will not do anything. I can press enter and it will go from one line to the next.

Comment: "Stops responding" indicates you never get out of your while loop. You'll need to use a debugger to figure out why, or you can print out the variables inside the loop to see why your expression is never true.

Comment: You problem is in findMin method! add System.out.println("here"); as soon as you get into the method. You will see an infinite loop.

Comment: Where is the variable named ***maxLessThanFirst*** declared?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Oh I see! Thank you. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your findMin method. Pass the array and zero for the index;

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int index) {
    if (index == numbers.length - 1) 
    {
        return numbers[index];
    }
    else
    {
        return Math.min(numbers[index], findMin(numbers, index + 1));
    }    
}
```

Comment: You don't mention the problem with the original `findMin` method. It's not an infinite loop. Try reducing the size of the array from 100 to 10 and you'll see that it finishes quickly. Not so quickly for 20, though.

Comment: Oh, I didn't let it run long enough to finish I guess.

Comment: It would be difficult to let it run long enough to finish at the original length of 100.

Answer (score 0):

Your `findMin` method is doubly recursive:

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return numbers[startIndex];
        // in the next line, we recurse looking for the minimum
    } else if (findMin(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) < numbers[endIndex]) {
        // we've found the minimum, but now we must recurse again to get it!
        return findMin(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
    } else {
        return numbers[endIndex];
    }
}
```

This transforms what should be a linear algorithm into an exponential one. If you log each time `findMin` is entered, you will find it increases rapidly with the size of the array. Experimentation shows that it is called 2^(x-1) + 2^(x-2) - 1 times, where x is the length of the array.

So if you had an array of size 10, it would be called 767 times. For an array of size 20, it would be called 786,431 times. Size 30, 25,165,823 times. Size 100 yields:

950,737,950,171,172,051,122,527,404,031 calls (950 octillion, 9.5 x 10^29).

Your program will not crash with a StackOverflowError because at no time does the stack *depth* exceed roughly the length of the array (plus one for the main), but it will take longer than the lifespan of the universe to run.

Changing `findMin` to this:

```
public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return numbers[startIndex];
    }
    // there's no need for an else since the if ended with a return
    int r = findMin(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1); // only recurse once
    if (r < numbers[endIndex]) {
        // we've found the minimum, return it without recursing again
        return r;
    }
    // again, no need for else, here
    return numbers[endIndex];
}
```

Now the algorithm only takes 20 calls for an array of size 20, 50 for size 50, 100 for size 100. The fact that you had already called `findMin` recursively to get the value to compare but were then calling it *again* to get the same value to return should have been a red flag. In many cases, such unnecessary repetition would merely be a minor annoyance; in this case, it was catastrophic.

Oh, I forgot to mention. The reason entering a *negative* number triggered the problem: Presumably, you don't always type 100 numbers in. I never did when I tried your program. It's too boring, and you can just end the list by entering a zero. When you allocate the array:

```
int[] numbers = new int[100];
```

The array is filled with zeros. So, if you enter ten numbers, the rest of the array will be zeros, and when we get to this line in the *first* call to `findMin`:

```
    if (findMin(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) < numbers[endIndex])
```

The number at the end will be zero, which is also the min. So we only recurse once, not twice. That will happen for most of the recursive calls, too; it will happen for all the ones at the long tail of zeros at the end of the array. It will only be when we get down into the entries where the user has actually entered a value where we will see the doubly-recursive behavior. If the user only enters about 10 numbers, we're safe.

But if the user enters even a single ***negative*** number, then that becomes the minimum and the zeros don't protect us. We hit the double recursion on **every** call, except for the one where `numbers[endIndex]` holds that negative number. Come to think of it, the reason I got 2^(x-1) + 2^(x-2) - 1 instead of just 2^x - 1 is because I always put the negative number in the *second* position in the array. So, depending on where the minimum value is, you could get performance better, or even worse, than what I describe above.

Comment: Wow! This is really helpful. I appreciate the effort you put into this.

Comment: @James It was an interesting question. When I first saw the second recursive call, I thought it would be a problem, but then I second-guessed myself, thinking it would be okay because it should run in linear time. It wasn't until I started trying it out, including variations with different inputs and different lengths, that I realized it was really the problem.